# index and match with multiple columns of similar content

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use Excel to find which employee was most recently at a jobsite. I have a table with employee names as headers, dates on the furthest left column, and the content is the job numbers of where they were that day.

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Is there a way to write a formula to find who was most recently at '20.022'?
Is there a way to write a formula to find how long ago that was from now?

thank you very much, I appreciate all you folks.

Comment: What if there are two on one day, what should be returned?

Comment: A list of both names, preferably.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more option - for most recent date:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,AGGREGATE(14,6,(B2:G15=J2)*ROW(B2:G15),1))
```

for name:

```
=INDEX(A1:G1,1,AGGREGATE(14,6,(A2:A15=K2)*((B2:G15=J2)*COLUMN(B2:G15)),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!